# poptrox add clickable link/button

Tags: javascript

I am working with poptrox and would like to add a button or link the iframe when it pops up. I need to be able to pick what pop ups have the extra button to. I would like the button to like to what the iframe is showing. I dont know if it would be better to add a button or turn the iframe to a big button.

https://github.com/ajlkn/jquery.poptrox

My code
-----HTML

```
<section class="thumbnails">
                            <div>
                            <a href="http://youtu.be/loGm3vT8EAQ" title="Test Text">
                            <img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" class="image"/>
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                            </a>

                                <a href="iframe.html" data-poptrox="iframe,600x400">
                                    <img src="images/thumbs/03.jpg" alt=""  title="thing"/>
                                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

Javastipt--

```
$(function() {

// Vars.
    var $window = $(window),
        $body = $('body'),
        $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

// Breakpoints.
    skel.breakpoints({
        xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
        large:  '(max-width: 1280px)',
        medium: '(max-width: 980px)',
        small:  '(max-width: 736px)',
        xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)'
    });

// Disable animations/transitions until everything's loaded.
    $body.addClass('is-loading');

    $window.on('load', function() {
        $body.removeClass('is-loading');
    });

// Poptrox.
    $window.on('load', function() {

        $('.thumbnails').poptrox({
            onPopupClose: function() { $body.removeClass('is-covered'); },
            onPopupOpen: function() { $body.addClass('is-covered'); },
            baseZIndex: 10001,
            useBodyOverflow: false,
            usePopupEasyClose: true,
            overlayColor: '#000000',
            overlayOpacity: 0.75,
            popupLoaderText: '',
            fadeSpeed: 500,
            usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
            usePopupCaption: true,
            windowMargin: (skel.breakpoint('small').active ? 5 : 50)
        });

    });
```

});

Comment: I think you should be more explicit about what you are trying to do. We are not soothsayers...

Comment: Got you it now?

Comment: I am not sure how to add a button to the pop up.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please add some code of your scenario then we can know a little about it?

I undestand you want to build a gallery using Poptrox but I don't know what you really miss.

For now maybe this snippet helps you. Give me a little more info and we can edit over it to see if we can give your solution.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#gallery').poptrox({
    usePopupCaption: true,
    usePopupNav: true,
    popupPadding: 0
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

a {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .1s;
  transition: opacity .1s;
}
a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

section:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.devmount {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 17px Arial;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: url(http://media.devmount.de/devmount_small_light.png) right center no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: background-position .3s, color .3s;
  transition: background-position .3s, color .3s;
}
.devmount span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}
.devmount:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-position: left center;
  color: transparent;
}
.devmount:hover span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/n33/jquery.poptrox/master/jquery.poptrox.js"></script>

<div id="gallery"> 
  <!-- Regular images -->
  <section>
    <!-- image 1--><a href="http://placehold.it/500/09f/fff.png"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/09f/fff.png&amp;text=image1" alt="" title="Just an image (#1)"/></a>
    <!-- image 2--><a href="http://placehold.it/500/0bf/fff.png"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/0bf/fff.png&amp;text=image2" alt="" title="Just an image (#2)"/></a>
    <!-- image 3--><a href="http://placehold.it/500/0df/fff.png"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/0df/fff.png&amp;text=image3" alt="" title="Just an image (#3)"/></a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <!-- YouTube: Must be in share format (http://youtu.be/xxxxxxxxxxx) --><a href="http://youtu.be/loGm3vT8EAQ" data-poptrox="youtube,800x480"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/CC181E/fff.png&amp;text=youtube" alt="" title="A YouTube Video"/></a>
    <!-- Vimeo: Must be in share format (http://vimeo.com/xxxxxxxx) --><a href="http://vimeo.com/22439234" data-poptrox="vimeo,800x480"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/69C8CE/fff.png&amp;text=vimeo" alt="" title="A Vimeo Video"/></a>
    <!-- Soundcloud: Must be in share format (https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/xxxxxxxx) --><a href="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/93549370" data-poptrox="soundcloud"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/FF5500/fff.png&amp;text=soundcloud" alt="" title="A Soundcloud Track"/></a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <!-- IFRAME: Link straight to whatever page you want to open --><a href="#" data-poptrox="iframe,600x400"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/07f/fff.png&amp;text=iframe" alt="" title="An IFRAME"/></a>
    <!-- AJAX: Link to whatever content you want to pull in (must be on the same domain)  --><a href="#" data-poptrox="ajax,600x400"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/07f/fff.png&amp;text=ajax" alt="" title="AJAX content"/></a>
    <!-- Ignore: Use this if you want a particular thumbnail to just link out to something --><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net" data-poptrox="ignore"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/07f/fff.png&amp;text=ignore" alt=""/></a>
  </section>
</div><a class="devmount" href="http://devmount.de" target="_blank">created by<span>devmount</span></a>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Let me give you a hand with your purpose now that I understand what you need.

Poptrox use his own methods. As you see there you can not only use to show images. But customization need to follow 'Poptrox rules'. You see it takes the image from href tag when you are using the gallery option so the posibilities are not much for customization.

First I recommend to you is give a look here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp to know the basis about how modal dialogs works. It Will give you a better comprehension. Now, about Poptrox. If you go Poptrox documentation: https://github.com/ajlkn/jquery.poptrox

Your options to give a customization of the modal dialog could be

> IFRAMEs
>
> ```
> Link format: Anything.
> Type: iframe
> Example:
>
> <a href="path/to/whatever.html" data-poptrox="iframe,600x400"><img src="path/to/thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
> ```
>
> AJAX Content
>
> ```
> Link format: Anything (as long as it's on the same domain)
> Type: ajax
> Example:
>
> <a href="path/to/whatever.html" data-poptrox="ajax,600x400"><img src="path/to/thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
> ```

Iframes open an ['iframe'](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).
AJAX is basically the same but Ajax do it asyncronous. Asyncronous means that it request to the server but he doesnt wait response to continue with execution.

Knowing it. You can configure your output HTML file with buttons, links using HTML. And show it in your modal, I think the best is to do it using ajax option.

Check this [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/oJQRZBr5vlDuQdcxJqF9/) I have done and sorry my english I am not native english speaker.

Comment: What you really miss?

Comment: I dont know how to add a button to the pop up

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check if it solves you something. I am gonna see if I can do a fast example for customization.

Comment: I added a example too

Answer (score 0):

you can also add **href** instead of simple text in title
change your code as:

```
<!-- image 1-->
<a href="http://placehold.it/500/09f/fff.png"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/09f/fff.png&amp;text=image1" alt="" title="<a href='https://freefrontend.com/'>Just an image (#1)</a> /></a>
```

This will now act as link only if the following changes are made.....

up untill now you would have come across a file "jquery.poptrox.min.js" , In that file find "captionText: r.attr('title')," and change that to "captionText: $.parseHTML(r.attr('title')),". now jQuery will parse the content of the title attribute as href instead of plain text.