# How to adjust the Poptrox Popup image size from Templated.co free template

Tags: css, image

I was using the same free template code, see link -> [poptrox add clickable link/button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438411/poptrox-add-clickable-link-button/65137174#65137174)
I just want to know how can I adjust the size and make it a bit bigger, Im talking about the Popping Image animation, yes the small box size where the image fitsw when you click it. see attached below, Thanks in Advance.[image]

Here's the exact code:

```
// Poptrox.
    $window.on('load', function() {

        $('.thumbnails').poptrox({
            onPopupClose: function() { $body.removeClass('is-covered'); },
            onPopupOpen: function() { $body.addClass('is-covered'); },
            baseZIndex: 10001,
            useBodyOverflow: false,
            usePopupEasyClose: true,
            overlayColor: '#000000',
            overlayOpacity: 0.75,
            popupLoaderText: '',
            fadeSpeed: 500,
            usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
            windowMargin: (skel.breakpoint('small').active ? 5 : 50)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this css part of the poptrox:

```
/* Poptrox */

.poptrox-popup {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 0.5em 3em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```